# Implementing a kotlin generic function that retrieves specific fields from a complex java object

Tags: java, kotlin, type-conversion, wrapper

I'm writing a Kotlin program that internally uses several functions of a java library (that i cannot modify).
One of this functions (let's call it "feval"), when called, returns an object that has the following structure: is an array of Objects of size 1, and its only member is an instance of com.mathworks.matlab.types.Struct. Each field of this struct is again an Array of size 1 whose only member is a variable which type can be int, double, Array etc...and it's the value I'm interested in.

I would like to wrap this mess with a class that provides methods to access directly the "interesting" values. This is my shot at it:

```
class ExecutionResult (fevalOutput: Array<Any>) {
private val rootObj = fevalOutput[0]
val rootStruct: Struct
init {
    if (rootObj is Struct) {
        rootStruct = rootObj
    }
    else {
        throw ExecutionResultException("The output doesn't match the expected format")
    }
}

fun _get (field: String) : Any {
    val container = rootStruct.get(field)
            ?: throw NoSuchFieldException("The requested field cannot be found in the result")
    if (container is Array<*>) {
        val value = container[0]
        if (value != null) {
            return value
        }
        else {
            throw NoSuchFieldException("The requested field cannot be found in the result")
        }
    }
    else{
        throw ExecutionResultException("The requested field has an unexpected format")
    }
}
inline fun <reified T> get (field: String) : T {
    val value = _get(field)
    if (value is T) {
        return value
    }
    else {
        throw ExecutionResultException(
                "The requested field is not a member of the specified class: ${T::class.java}," +
                        " but a member of: ${value::class.java}")
    }
}}
```

So now,from my code I can do something like:

```
val output = engine.feval<Array<Any>>(1,functionName, *transmissionParameters.getParameters())
        val result = ExecutionResult(output)
        val simpleValue = result.get<Double>("simpleValue"))
```

Which is basically what I want.
However this doesn't always work. For instance, sometimes the nested value I'm looking for is an array of arrays of double. And if I do:

```
val moreComplexValue = result.get<Array<Array<Double>>>("moreComplexValue"))
```

I generate the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" matlabdriver.ExecutionResultException: The requested field is not a member of the specified class: class [[Ljava.lang.Double;, but a member of: class [[D
```

The problem, if I understand correctly, is due to the fact that I'm trying to convert an Array of java native double into an Array of Double (class)

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to resolve this and/or improve my wrapper class in general?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that type erasure does not preserve the nested types of generics. In your case, `Array<Any>` will result in `Array::class.java`, and so does `Array<Array<Double>>`. Even with reified types, only the top-level class is available inside the function.

The Jackson (JSON serialization) library faces the same problem when deserializing to generic types such as `List<MyClass>`. They let you explicitly specify the type parameters:

```
// represents the generic type Outer<Inner>
val type: JavaType = mapper.typeFactory.constructParametricType(Outer::class.java, Inner::class.java)
```

I would suggest you provide a similar mechanism to provide all types in the hierarchy. Maybe inform yourself about Jackson's `JavaType` to see the mechanism. With Kotlin, you can still use generic syntax with reified type, e.g.:

```
val type = dim3<Array, Array, Double>()
// or easier:
val type = array2<Double>()
```

You could then pass that type (which stores the generic type parameters as class objects) as the first argument to your function:

```
feval(type, otherArgs...)
```

`type` itself could be a `data class MatlabType(val subtypes: List<KClass>)` with lots of factory functions such as `array2()`.